# sitecore 8.1 Launchpad showing HTTP 404 error

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

Not sure what is I missing here. No analytics graph showing up
[image: 404 error]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Analytics?
If not, try to disable it and try again.

I was having similar issue, i haven't setup xDB for Analytics.
So, it was giving me error while getting Tracking information.

Comment: Yes, I am using Analytics and also setup xDB.